# HTML / VBA Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I have a little problem with a VBA and HTML routine. I have to select from the link https://www.betexplorer.com/next/soccer/ the "Sort by:" drop-down menu and select the "Leagues" item. I can't do this via the VBA.

This is the code that I wrote

```
Sub Scarica()
Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLDoc1 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim Dropdowns As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim post As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim Elem As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Application.StatusBar = "Download Elenco Campionati odierni in corso..."
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual


IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.betexplorer.com/next/soccer/"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

'==================================================
' THIS IS THE PART THAT I CAN'T WRITE
'==================================================

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
Set post = HTMLDoc.getElementById("wrap-header__list__item.semilong")




    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
'==================================================
'==================================================
```

This is my first message and I'm not able to insert the HTML code of the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can isolate the correct dropdown item for selection by combining the id of the parent `select` with the [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for the `value` attribute of the appropriate child `option` tag. The parent `select` is expecting an `onchange` event which you need to attach and dispatch.

Parent `div` by `id` and child `option` by `value`:

[image]

Event handler:

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, evt As Object

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.betexplorer.com/next/soccer/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector("#nr-all [value='2']").Selected = True

        Set evt = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        evt.initEvent "change", True, False
        .document.querySelector("#nr-all select").dispatchEvent evt
        Stop                                     '< delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you are most welcome. Let me know if it works as you wanted.

Comment: Please could you answer to the question below?

Comment: hi, this should be posted as a new question

Answer (score 0):

The way @QHarr explained is just perfect. Or you can also do something like this with your existing code.

```
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.betexplorer.com/next/soccer/"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
With HTMLDoc.getElementById("next-filter-sort").all(1).all(0)
    .Focus
    .Value = "2" '"Leagues"
End With
```

Comment: MAny thanks your solution is more simple. I would never have succeeded without your help. Many thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Sorry both codes work, but how come when I try to extrapolate the name of each league, those are loaded by the "Kick off times" and not by Leagues?
he code that I used is:

```
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://www.betexplorer.com/next/soccer/"

    Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    .document.querySelector("#nr-all [value='2']").Selected = True

    Set evt = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    evt.initEvent "change", True, False
    .document.querySelector("#nr-all select").dispatchEvent evt

    Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

End With



i = 9 'Riga di inizio copia dati
j = 0 'Colonna di inizio copia dati
```

Range("A10:A1005").ClearContents 'Pulisce la Zona dove saranno incollati i dati

Set mycoll = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
For Each myItm In mycoll

```
    For Each trtr In myItm.Rows
        If trtr.classname = "js-tournament" Then
            inizio = InStr(trtr.innerHTML, "href=") + 6
            fine = InStr(trtr.innerHTML, "><i") - 1
            fedhtml = Trim(Mid(trtr.innerHTML, inizio, fine - inizio))
            campionato = Split(Replace(fedhtml, "/soccer/", ""), "/")
            campionato = Trim(campionato(1))
                Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = trtr.innerText
                Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Select
                Selection.RowHeight = 15
                i = i + 1
        End If
    Next trtr
```

Next myItm